# Add caption to jquery caroufredsel plugin items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use the second Example of caroufredsel  plugin (see this page http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/ ) and I'm trying to add a caption for each picture.

I have make it with il and lis
this is my html code:

```
<div class="list_carousel">
    <ul id="foo2">
        <li><img src="images/carousel/billboard_img1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/carousel/billboard_img2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/carousel/billboard_img3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/carousel/billboard_img4.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="pager_container" class="pager">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I add a div with text into it under a ´li´, I get the same same text in the 4 ´lis´.

How can I fix this problem to get different texts for each item?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to include the `<div>` inside the `<li>` tags like this:

```
<div class="list_carousel">
    <ul id="foo2">
        <li><img src="images/carousel/billboard_img1.jpg" /><div>MyText</div></li>
        <li><img src="images/carousel/billboard_img2.jpg" /><div>SomeOtherText</div></li>
        <li><img src="images/carousel/billboard_img3.jpg" /><div>MoreHere</div></li>
        <li><img src="images/carousel/billboard_img4.jpg" /><div>SampleText</div></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="pager_container" class="pager">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, it was a problem of css, it's solved now :)
Thank you for help.