# Adding caption to images when hover

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery caroufredsel and I want have a caption for my items.
I know this can be solved using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430769/add-caption-to-jquery-caroufredsel-plugin-items), but I am using this way and I don't have any `li` :

```
<div id="foo2">
    <img src="Images\01.jpg" width="150"/>
    <img src="Images\02.jpg" width="150" />
    <img src="Images\03.jpg" width="150" />
    <img src="Images\04.jpg" width="150" />
    <img src="Images\05.jpg" width="150" />
    <img src="Images\06.jpg" width="150" />
    <img src="Images\07.jpg" width="150" />
</div>
```

How can I show a caption on my images when hover with effect with a little code?

Comment: *sidenote:* you're using backslash, you should use `/` (slash)

Comment: can we have the details of your jQuery plugin ?

Comment: sure, I am using this jquery plug-in : www.caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Comment: @SirwanAfifi... Check it now my updated code. Its working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your HTML code:

```
<div id="foo2">
   <img src="Images\01.jpg" width="150" /><span>image 1</span>
   <img src="Images\02.jpg" width="150" /><span>image 2</span>
   <img src="Images\03.jpg" width="150" /><span>image 3</span>
   <img src="Images\04.jpg" width="150" /><span>image 4</span>
   <img src="Images\05.jpg" width="150" /><span>image 5</span>
   <img src="Images\06.jpg" width="150" /><span>image 6</span>
   <img src="Images\07.jpg" width="150" /><span>image 7</span>
</div>
```

and in your CSS:

```css
#foo2 img {
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#foo2 span {
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

Here is my working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ponrajpaul/quAqS/

showing caption on mouse hover

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("#foo2 img").hover(function () {       
    $(this).next().css({"display" : "inline-block"});
  },function () {       
    $(this).next().css({"display" : "none"}); 
  });
});
```

and update **CSS**
change display value on span

```
#foo2 span {
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

check my new updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ponrajpaul/quAqS/1/

**UPDATED 9/8/2017**

The same can be achieved by pure CSS, without Javascript. Thanks @Elise Chant

```
 #foo2 span{
   display: none;
 }
 #foo2 img:hover + span{
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Has good browser support as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ponrajpaul/quAqS/20/

Comment: now how can I show this caption when mouse over, first I want it would be hidden.

Comment: *sidenote:* IE7 has bug on `display: inline-block;`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Its working fine in ie7. As per your sidenote <span>,<a> tags are natural inline elements.@ShivanRaptor

Answer (score 0):

Show your captions on hover with CSS.

```
span {
  display: none;
}

#foo2:hover + span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```